# C++ Extracting and counting number of words in a text file

Tags: c++

My task is to read from a text file and count the number of words while displaying the text to the console. Whenever I call my "getString" function, my "numCount" goes to 0. if I comment my "getString" function out the numCount shows the correct number of words. So both functions look like they work it just when they are both called then I get these problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getFileInfo(ifstream &inFile);
int numOfWords(ifstream& inFile); // counts number of words
string getString(ifstream &inFile); // retrieves string from textfile


int main(){

    string fileName, words, str;
    ifstream inFile;
    int count;

    getFileInfo(inFile);
    str = getString(inFile);
    count = numOfWords(inFile);

    cout << "In the sentence, '" << str << "', there are " << count << " words " << endl;


}

void getFileInfo(ifstream &inFile){

    string fileName;

    do{

        cout << "Please enter the filename: " << endl;
        cin >> fileName;

        inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

        if(!inFile){

            cout << "Invalid try again" << endl;

        }
    }while(!inFile);

}

int numOfWords(ifstream& inFile){

    string fileName, words, str;
    int numCount =0;

    while(inFile >> words){
        ++numCount;
    }

    return numCount;

}

string getString(ifstream &inFile){

    string str;

    while(inFile)
        getline(inFile, str);

    return str;

}
```

Comment: `getString` reads the entire file. There is nothing left for `numOfWords` to read. You will have rewind the file seek to the beginning and maybe clear the EOF flag depending on which C++ standard you're compiling to.

Comment: thank u so much, just fixed it and it works great. @user4581301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not resetting the stream after `getString()`

C++ iostreams have a sort of metaphorical cursor, where every bit you read moves the cursor to the next bit (so you can read it without having to manually move the cursor). The problem in your code is that the cursor position ends up at the end of `inFile` after `getString()`, meaning the loop in `getNumOfWords()` never runs.

What you need to do is reset the stream after `getString()`. Example:

```cpp
std::string getString(ifstream& inFile) {
  ...
  inFile.clear() // <-- You may need this depending on your iostream implementation to clear the EOF failbit
  inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

  return str;

}
```